# Find percentage difference between variables in a vector C++

Tags: c++, algorithm, vector

I am a novice to C++, but I am trying to take a vector with an variable amount of elements in descending order and finding the percentage drop between each element.

For example, if I have {10 5 2.5 1 ], how can I output a vector showing [50 50 40} showing the percentage drop.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What have you tried, and where did you get stuck? Are you having trouble with the arithmetic to calculate the percentage, the loop to iterate over the vector, or something else?

Comment: iterator adjacent_difference( iterator start, iterator end, iterator result, BinaryFunction f );

Comment: So I am drawing the numbers from vector "output" and placing the percentages in vector "percentageDiff". The vector "output" changes size based on user input. I am not sure how to do the arithmetic for each consecutive element.

         std::vector<double> percentageDiff;
         int numlength=output.size;
         for (int i=0;i<numlength;i++)
         {

         }

Answer (score 3):

Either you should write a corresponding loop yourself or you can use standard algorithm std::transform. For example

```
    std::vector<double> v = { 10, 5, 2.5, 1 };

    std::transform( std::next( v.begin() ), v.end(), v.begin(), std::ostream_iterator<double>( std::cout, " " ),
        []( double x, double y ) { return ( x * 100 / y ); } );
    std::cout << std::endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

In your iterating loop, you will have two indices:

- first number index
- second number index

The math would look like:

```
  abs(vector[first number index] - vector[ second number index])
    / abs(vector[first number index])
```

You should be the result into another vector.

The loop should increment the indices by 1.

Also, you'll need a special case for when the second number index goes beyond the size of the vector.

Answer (score 0):

here's the loop way Vlad mentioned:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    double val;
    std::vector<double> values, percentages;

    while(std::cin >> val) {        //get values from user
        values.push_back(val);      //on linux, terminate with CTRL+D
    }
    for(unsigned i = 0; i < values.size() - 1; ++i) {       //calculate percentage differences
        percentages.push_back((values[i+1] / values[i]) * 100); //and populate percentage vector
    }
    for(auto it : percentages) {    //print percentage vector
        std::cout << it << " ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

and here's the output it generates:

```
10
5
2.5
1
50 50 40
```